# Illustrator Bounding Box not correcty showing up (set to contur)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've got a problem in Illustrator with the bounding box, I've already searched the whole web but i can't find a fix for this!
Is there a way to set the bounding box always to the path, not the contur ? I know there is probably a simple solution to this, but i really can't seem to find it.

This is really annoying, i hope you can help me out with this!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under *Preferences → General*, there is an option called "Use Preview Bounds".

[image]

Turning this on will force the bounding box to fit to the visual appearance of what you select, so it will include strokes or any other appearance attributes you have. I assume you have this turned on....

Turning it off will force the bounding box to fit to path data only; exactly as you want.

Comment: thank you so much! can't believe i was that blind... you saved my day thanks a lot!